# msgraph api, filter shared mailboxes by a search string

Tags: email, microsoft-graph-api

Is there a rest api in msgraph which I can use to filter a list of shared mailboxes based on a given substring.  My idea is that if I am given a string `test` I should be able to search all shared mailboxes which contain the given string `test`.  I searched and went through the msgraph documentation but I didn't find an endpoint which allows me to do this.  I can read the messages but cannot do a search for the available mailboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no Microsoft Graph Endpoint to list shared mailboxes which could provide query/search capability.

I suggest you create a feature request for it on the [Microsoft 365 Developer Platform](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform) so that it may be implemented in future.